# How to get unique value from array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array inputs like this :

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,6];
$array2 = [1,3];
$output = array_merge(array_diff($array1,$array2),array_diff($array2,$array1));
```

Now I want to check array1 with array 2 and eliminate 1 and 3 in `$array1`

and the output I am expecting is

```
$output = [2,4,6];
```

but in this method I get some bugs, when array2 have single value e.g.:  `$array2 = [1];` , `$array1 = [1,2,3,4,6];` the output should be  `$output = [2,3,4,6];`. But I am getting `$array1` all values `[1,2,3,4,6];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple :)

(Just un-complicate your code and you don't need anything new for that)

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,6);
$array2 = array(1,3);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/11vRIAAK)**

In Your style it can even be a one liner :P

```
<?php  print_r(array_diff(array(1,2,3,4,6), array(1,3))); ?>
```